# the hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file- Creating a .cat file for an edited .inf?

Tags: usb, drivers, xbox360, cat, inf

I got a rock candy xbox360 controller today and its not plug and play as an xbox 360 controller on pc. I edited the .inf file and now the driver may work, but i dont know how to make the .bat file agree with my edits.

Ive tried this: https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-device-driver-signing but it didnt work. The edited driver is now reconized as compatible with my controller, but "the hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file"

Can i unsign an installed driver and make a new sign, can i force it to ignore it another way? i just wanted to play a game x.x

Comment: Can you unsign a signed driver, all that would do is, leave you with an unsigned driver.